# Version upgrade to scikit-learn

Tags: macos, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I wanted to do LDA on some data and so followed this example:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_vs_lda.html#example-decomposition-plot-pca-vs-lda-py

however, on trying:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis
```

I got an import error. Huh, maybe this is a new function, I thought. So I updated scikit-learn via conda from 0.15.2 to 0.17. But now I can't even import sklearn:

```
    import sklearn
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/__init__.py", line 213, in <module>
    from .csr import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I tried updating numpy and scipy using both pip and conda to no avail. I then tried a complete clean re-install of anaconda by:

```
rm -rf ~/anaconda
```

and a subsequent download of the .pkg from http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#anaconda-install

Still I get the same error. Here are my OS and package details:

```
Mac OSX 10.5.2
bash-3.2$ conda -V
conda 3.18.6

scipy==0.16.0
numpy==1.9.1
scikit-learn==0.17
```

The last of these via pip freeze since I can't import it. I'm going nuts here. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Have you attempted `conda update -all`? To make sure all other dependencies are met.

Comment: Hi Leb, yes I tried that to no avail. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
conda install numpy=1.10.1
```

I've had that `module compiled against API version a but this version of numpy is 9` error before, and this solved it for me.

Comment: Hi @kwinkunks, thanks. I tried this, but it claims that 1.10.1 is already installed:
<code>
bash-3.2$ conda install numpy=1.10.1
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ..................
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at //anaconda:
#
numpy                     1.10.1                   py27_0    defaults
</code>
Formatting seems to be messed up there, sorry.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a $PATH issue now, but not sure of the specifics. running which -a python I get //anaconda/bin//python followed by /usr/bin/python, and running python I definitely get the anaconda version. But running python and then importing numpy gives 1.9.2

Comment: Fixed! In my attempts to solve the original problem, I forgot that I pip installed a version of numpy via pip, and it was this version which was being picked up by anaconda. Accepting answer from @kwinkunks since it led me to the solution. Thanks all.